# "the payment cash" or "the cash payment"

Tags: word-order, noun-phrases

> He said they will accept the payment ((that is)) cash on the delivery.

> He said they will accept the cash payment on the delivery.

Which phrase would be better? Should I “cash” before payment or after payment? When I use “cash” as an adjective should I use it after payment?

Answer (score 4):

"Payment cash," while an unusual phrase, ought to mean "the cash which is used for the payment." The phrase "cash payment" is more common, and means "the payment which is in the form of cash," emphasizing that other forms of payment are not acceptable.

If the intent is to emphasize that only cash is acceptable, the second option would be good. Otherwise, it might be simplest to simply say "...accept the payment on delivery."